# 2 OnClickListeners for one Button cannot resolve the OnClick Listener

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

I added the following lines of Code into my OnCreate method.My goal is to assign a button to two functions and to call them up alternately. With the first click the text of the button should be changed and the EditText should be editable. At the second click, the fields should no longer be editable and the button text should change to the first alternative. I have implemented two OnClickListeners and the program structure seems logical to me. Nevertheless, I get an error message; "Cannot resolve symbol onClickListener". What can I do to get the setup described above up and running? Thanks for all responses!

```
private Button ProfilUpdate;
ProfilUpdate=findViewById(R.id.buttonProfilUpdate);
.
.
.
.

     final ProfilUpdate.OnClickListener listener2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ProfilUpdate.setText("Profil bearbeiten");
                profilVorname.setFocusable(false);
            }
        };
        ProfilUpdate.OnClickListener listener1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ProfilUpdate.setText("Änderungen speichern");
                profilVorname.setFocusable(true);
                v.setOnClickListener(listener2);
            }
        };
        ProfilUpdate.setOnClickListener(listener1);
```

Comment: check my suggestion please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you create a `boolean` `isFirstClick = true` , and then check it in the same `listener`

```
ProfilUpdate.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isFirstClick){
                //Do the job for the first click process 
                isFirstClick= false;
                }else {
                //Do the job for the second click process
                isFirstClick= true;
                }

            }
        };
        ProfilUpdate.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one click listener on one view at a time. Use `ProfileUpdate.setOnClickListener(listener object)`. To get the `alternate` functionality, you can define a Boolean to keep track of the state, for the example, define a class variable at the top `Boolean shouldChangeText = true`, and in the `onClick` body in the listener, do something like:

```
If (shouldChangeText) { // change the text
 }
else { // clear the text
}
shouldChangeText = !shouldChangeText
```